# How to store credentials Gmail API

Tags: python, django, web, gmail-api

I've connected Gmail API to Django project. I have a problem with storing credentials of every user. What is the most correct way to store them, so every users can log in? Without storing it just creates one file for one user and that's all. Should I create a database?

This is my "quickstart" file from Google:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# user = User
# storage = (CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential') As you see I tried it here but it didn't go well
# credential = storage
#
# storage.__add__(credential)

# Setup the Gmail API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


def go():

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    # if not labels:
    #     print('No labels found.')
    # else:
    #     print('Labels:')
    #     for label in labels:
    #         print(label['name'])

pass
```

Comment: If you have a django project do you not already have a database (e.g. the default django DB stooring all your user info etc)?

Comment: @TomDalton yeah, there is but I'm bad in that.

Comment: Might be worth looking at something like https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html that shows you how to add additional info to the existing User model, which would allow you to store the users gmail credentials as part of the user model.

Comment: @TomDalton I found this one but some code is out of date and I get red lines in Django 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django#storage
It can't find django_orm